# can't install (in Vmware Virtual maschin) windows 2008 R2 64 bit on hp DL 380 G4?

Tags: windows, vmware-esx, hp

when we want to install W2008 R2 64bit error has accured and alert:
[image]

Comment: @saber tabatabaee yazdi Do you enable virtualisation mode in bios?

Comment: @sanja-melnichuk VT Enables = YES

Comment: My HP DL380 G4 doesn't support hardware virtualization. Are you sure that yours does?

Comment: My HP ML380 G4 support and when i VT enabled solved the problem like this not this.

Comment: 2008R2 is 64-bit only. Does your DL380G4 have 64-bit processors?

Comment: @Tom, the DL380 G4 didn't come with 32, only 64bit processors. According to the Spec sheet those processors did not have VT-x, though some have reported having processors that weren't on the original spec sheet (those still didn't support VT-x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the option is in the BIOS or not, the Xeons that were available in the G4 were Nocona Cores, which do not support VT-x.

Comment: Mine has 2 MB of L2 cache, making it an Irwindale rather than a Nocona. I believe lots of other models did, as well. Either way, your answer is still correct—neither the Nocona nor the Irwindale Xeons support VT-x.

Answer (score 3):

@saber tabatabaee:
Try this tool: [CPU Identification Utility](http://www.vmware.com/download/shared_utilities.html)
Displays CPU features for VMotion compatibility, EVC and indicates 64-bit VMware support.